# Img onclick function

Tags: javascript, html, image, onclick

I have few images and when clicked, I want to run code, let's say alert image number.

```
<img onclick="picture(1)" src="asd.jpg">
<img onclick="picture(2)" src="sdf.jpg">
<script>
   function picture(picnumber){
   alert(picnumber);
   }
</script>
```

It worked, when I was alerting string, not variable.

Edit: I'm sorry for including example and not my actual code, I thought it was ok, solution given below however didn't fix my code:

```
<body>
    <style>
        img{
            height:80px;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        function picture(picbumber){
            alert(picnumber); 
        }
    </script>
    <h1>GALLERY</h1>
    <div class="photos">
        <img onclick="picture(1)" src="https://i.insider.com/5f5a5f37e6ff30001d4e8163?width=700"/>
        <img onclick="picture(2)" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSChu52FnNKfSPRTMY8HIXei8leVAMvkURqqQ&usqp=CAU">
        <img onclick="picture(3)" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSIvgVWXKciw_UZIuzVenY4QvmCbDQb43J1lQ&usqp=CAU">
        <img onclick="picture(4)" scr="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSY9xhvbRt8gXsEyO1dOW41asBHrEb2mZkRgQ&usqp=CAU">
        <img onclick="picture(5)" src="https://dkt6rvnu67rqj.cloudfront.net/cdn/ff/T8cy0-640W8sartvA9TWmv08NbGPFxsVvf8gFtBDE08/1577112797/public/styles/600x400/public/media/int_files/elephant_in_tanzania.jpg?h=f507d761&itok=Ei8OXcGi">
        <img onclick="picture(6)" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR1u8AKJBUZdSX7SIHvd8R1SiYyypx7elpstQ&usqp=CAU">
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: you are passing "picbumber" and alerting "picnumber", you have a typo

Comment: Friick, I felt like I checked names of variables ten times. Works now.

Comment: that's why you always have your dev tools open while developing, there you see stuff like that immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add the script code in head section. See my demo here.

````
<head>
    <script>
        function picture(picnumber){
            alert(picnumber)
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <img onclick="picture(1)" src="./asd.jpg" />
    <img onclick="picture(2)" src="./sdf.jpg" />
</body>
</html>```
````

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

just change the order, in onclick you are executing a function that is not defined yet otherwise

```
<script>
   function picture(picnumber){
   alert(picnumber);
   }
</script> 
<img onclick="picture(1)" src="asd.jpg">
<img onclick="picture(2)" src="sdf.jpg">
```

Comment: Worked with example I gave above, I thought it's ok just to write example. Needles to say it didn't with my actual code, I added it in the post.